# Searching two mysql columns added together for one variable

Tags: mysql

I currently have a search form which should allow a user to search for a customers full name and it will return the row. 

For Example: A user searches for "Mr. N Mallow" and it will return the row which matches that query. Since I am new to MySQL I need some help, I've tried + but that has no effect, probably because it's not standard mysql or something like that.

```
select * 
  from mooring 
       left join customer 
       on mooring.assignedTo = customer.id 
 where mooring.Number like \"$var\" 
    or (customer.TitleName + customer.Surname = '$var')
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select * from mooring 
left join customer on mooring.assignedTo = customer.id 
where mooring.Number like \"$var\" OR (customer.TitleName + customer.Surname = '$var')

Try [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) or [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), which join strings together (the first version is "with separator"):

```
CONCAT(customer.TitleName,' ',customer.Surname)
```

or

```
CONCAT_WS(' ',customer.TitleName,customer.Surname)
```